# How to show all errors in the browser on Flask framework?

Tags: python, browser, frameworks, flask

I use Flask framework and build a Python project. It shows all errors on the page when I run a python file on the SSH shell.

After I installed WSGI to run the server automatically, it started not showing errors on the browser. It only shows "Internal Server Error" if there is an error.

my python file has this option at the end.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000,debug=True)
```

I would like to look at all errors to figure out problems. Is there a way to look at all errors on the browser?

Comment: This may help [activating-the-flask-debugger-when-running-under-mod-wsgi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10566107/activating-the-flask-debugger-when-running-under-mod-wsgi)

Comment: @flyer I did that. I can't see the errors..

Comment: Is your WSGI process running behind another server (like Apache or Nginx)? If so, then are the 500 errors actually your server not correctly configured to connect to the WSGI process, and you need to look at the server (Apache or Nginx) logs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally noticed that it doesn't show errors on the browser because I run the server under WSGI mod.

Python Flask shows detailed errors on the browser if I run the python file on the shell.

```
app.debug = True
```

This is a command to look at detailed errors.

So, I had to turn off WSGI mod to run python file to look at detailed errors that Flask supported.

Comment: how to turn off the wsgi mode in flask?

Answer (score 1):

Please someone explain to me why the following approach doesnt display the erros in the browser which is what i want to do:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
application = app
```

Its very tedieous task to always have to `tail -f ../logs/error_log`