# Logging my own messages in flask

Tags: python, logging, flask

I was trying to follow the flask error handling tutorial - http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/errorhandling/#logging-to-a-file.

When I try to create the handler I am getting error

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/FlaskTest/FlaskTest/store.log'
```

I just want to log some data to a file for further analysis. What is the easiest way to do this?

EDIT:

Adding some more info: I am running the web application through the wsgi packaging and serving through apache. I understand user roles and need to grant permission :

```
logfile = logging.FileHandler("/var/www/FlaskTest/FlaskTest/store.log")
```

As you see I have tried targeting the www directory, should I be targeting another directory? I also don't want to expose the application by giving it unnecessary permissions. Is there a simple way to write objects to a file for later analysis in flask?

Comment: show us some code please

Comment: This typically means that process running your flask application does not have the user permissions to create a new file in `/var/www/FlaskTest/FlaskTest`, or it does not have the permissions to write to the file `/var/www/FlaskTest/FlaskTest/store.log`.

Comment: ok turns out if I am using apache-wsgi I need to tell wsgi to make the changes as here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10566107/activating-the-flask-debugger-when-running-under-mod-wsgi

Answer (score 5):

The code is (probably) fine.  The error is about OS permissions.  The app is running as a user that does not have write permissions to the directory.  You need to fix this outside of Flask.