# Why isn't Flask giving me an interactive debugger?

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi, werkzeug

Here's a simple Flask app with a syntax error (it should be `sys.version`, not `sys.version()`

```
from flask import Flask, url_for, request, render_template
import sys

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    version = sys.version()
    return "This is the index page.  Python version info: {}".format(version)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When I run it locally and try to access http://localhost:5000, I get the nice Werkzeug debugger:

[image]

but when I run it on a remote server (Apache 2.4.17, mod_wsgi 4.4.21), I only get a generic 500 error page:

[image]

I've tried various things to make this work:

- set `app.debug = True` right after `app = Flask(__name__)`
- based on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10566107/activating-the-flask-debugger-when-running-under-mod-wsgi), I tried adding this code as well:

`from werkzeug.debug import DebuggedApplication
application = DebuggedApplication(app, True)`

but nothing seems to help.

I know that the debugger doesn't work in forked environments, but according to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10566107/activating-the-flask-debugger-when-running-under-mod-wsgi#comment20593300_10568135), the default mode for mod_wsgi is to **not** be forked.  My Apache config is:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess flasktest user=david group=devgrp threads=1 python-path=/apps/www/80/wsgi-scripts/FlaskTest:/apps/.virtualenvs/flasktest/lib/python3.4/site-packages
```

So why can't I get the pretty debugger?

**EDIT:** Here's the modified file with my additions (that aren't working)

```
from flask import Flask
import sys

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)
app.debug = True

from werkzeug.debug import DebuggedApplication
application = DebuggedApplication(app, True)  

@app.route('/')
def index():   
    version = sys.version()
    return "This is the index page.  Python version info: {}".format(version)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add WSGI middleware to a Flask app, wrap and replace the app's `wsgi_app` attribute.  In the case of the debug middleware, set `app.debug = True` as well so that Flask doesn't convert exceptions to 500 responses.

```
app.debug = True
app.wsgi_app = DebuggedApplication(app.wsgi_app, evalex=True)
```

---

It is a security risk to run the debugger on a public server.  Despite the recent change requiring a PIN before running code, the debugger may still be insecure in unforseen ways.  Typically, you get information about errors in production by using logging.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32722523/400617) is a good basic summary of how to set that up.

---

Your method would probably work if you had replaced `app` rather than calling it `application`.  mod_wsgi was probably picking up `app` before `application`, so it was still running the original app.  It's still recommended to wrap `app.wsgi_app` though.